# Autoincrement using Sequences is not working as expected

Tags: talend

I am currently working on a job something like this

[image]

The design is to,extract some data from customers,(say first name,last name) to one excel file,other data (say address) is to goto other excel file,i added a identity to tMap `Numeric("s1",1,1)` but it is starting from 1,3,5,7,9,11,13.... and on other excel it getting 2,4,6,8,10,12,...

but i need both excel to have same identity 1,2,3,4,5,6,....N

so that i can map the records

so can somebody guide me on this?

## edit:

The autoincrement returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,... this is fine when thers only one tMap component in the job,but not similar when 2 tMaps are used ?

Comment: y do you need treplicate? rather than tMap?

Comment: @george,that the way to move same data to 2 or more components ?

Comment: You could use multiple outputs per tMap, so you can leave the tReplicate, which could make your job nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the numeric sequence is static. Since you have only one sequence called "s1", it will be incremented twice at every iteration (one time for each tMap it's invoked in).

Just use some unique labels (ie. "s1" and "s2") to force the use of two independent sequences, thus the solution of your problem.

Comment: +1 :)whoa !! nice catch @Gabriele,,thanks..that's it !!

Comment: It might be preferable to assign the sequence variable before the tReplicate instead.

Comment: as far I understand, he needs two indipendent primary keys. The fact they are equals is...kind of side-effect I guess.

Comment: @GabrieleB..[can you check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521895/validate-a-csv-file-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi ok, boss ;)