# Convert String field to delimited file (.csv)

Tags: java, mysql, csv, talend

I have a mysql table that has a column with the type longtext, this column containt the content of a csv file. Is there a way to create from the content of this column a csv file and extract data from it by using talend ?

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the String from the DB using the proper Input component. Then use tExtractDelimitedField to split this long String string against a separator character (the comma, I guess). Don't forget to specify carefully your output schema

Finally, use tFileDelimitedOut to write the delimited file with data from the outgoing connection on the file system.

This could help: [Validate a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521895/validate-a-csv-file-using-regular-expressions/21582087#21582087)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, request the string out of the database, open a file and write the string to it - where's your actual problem?